# Context Bounds and Classes

Tags: scala, implicit

What is wrong with the following function definition.

```
def f[A: Ordered] (a: A, b: A): Boolean = a < b
```

I get can not resolve symbol <. Since Ordered is a context class of A shouldnt it be able to resolve < ?  What am I missing?

Comment: For me `Ordered` is not a typeclass, but a base trait for plain inheritance. So either you update to `def f[A <: Ordered[_]](a: A, b: A): Boolean = a < b`, or you use the `Ordering` typeclass keeping the view bounds: `def f[T : Ordering](a: T, b: T): Boolean = { val order = implicitly[Ordering[T]]; order.compare(a, b) < 0 }` or `def f[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit order: Ordering[T]): Boolean = order.compare(a, b) < 0`

Comment: @cchantep This should be an (the) answer, not a comment.

Comment: So scala not actually checking what we have as a type parameter? typeclass or trait ?

Comment: Scala doesn't know whether a trait is intended to be used as a typeclass. Any typeconstructor that has exactly one parameter can be used as a context bound.

Answer (score 5):

`Ordered` is not a typeclass, but a base trait for plain inheritance.

So either you update to ...

```
def f[A <: Ordered[_]](a: A, b: A): Boolean = a < b
```

... or you use the `Ordering` typeclass keeping the context bounds:

```
def f[T : Ordering](a: T, b: T): Boolean = {
  val order = implicitly[Ordering[T]]
  order.lt(a, b)
}

// Or:
def f[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit order: Ordering[T]): Boolean = order.lt(a, b)
```

> Personally I don't recommend the implicit conversion from `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` (auto-magic stuff).

Answer (score 2):

[`Ordered[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.math.Ordered) is a trait which extends the `Comparable[T]` interface in Java. You implement it on a class where you want to compare the current instance of your class with another instance of that same class. What you're actually looking for is to use [`Ordering[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) which extends `Comparator[T]` in Java. It takes two elements and tells you if one is less than\equal to\larger than the other. As you're using Context Bounds, you can access the `Ordering[T]` via `implicitly`

```
def f[A: Ordering](a: A, b: A): Boolean = implicitly[Ordering[A]].lt(a, b)
```

As @m-z said, you can also `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` to use the `<` method:

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
def f[A: Ordering](a: A, b: A): Boolean = a < b
```

Comment: You could also `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` to write `a < b`

Comment: @m-z Added! Thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah I just find this unnecessarily complicated, why cant they just do it how haskell does it with type classes. Both implicitly[Ordering[A]].lt(a, b) and import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._ just make it seem unnecessarily complicated

Comment: Just curious as to we can use <% (view bound) instead of : (context bound). Is view bound deprecated, and is there a reason why you would use viewbound over context bounds and vice versa. Should I just ask this as a separate question or is here fine?

Comment: `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` is for implicit conversion, so related to the functional concept of typeclass (and can make the code quite unmaintainable).

Comment: @Abdul View Bounds are deprecated in Scala. They allowed you to view type `A` and type `B` by providing an implicit conversion. Context Bounds are about providing an implicit value where for any type `A`, you have an additional value of type `B[A]`.